# I managed to completely remove my ethernet card, even from BIOS

Tags: networking, ethernet, bios, lan

The problem is that I can't use my built in ethernet card. BIOS can't see it if I use SMART LAN it runs only "Virtual Cable Test", Windows can't use the card obviously, not even Xubuntu. Here is what I have been doing which might have caused the removal of the card.

I have installed Ubuntu/xubuntu with XFCE alongside Windows on another HDD.

I started to customize it a bit to fit my needs, added programs, utils etc. After that I wanted to enable audio output to 2 different devices at once (speakers/headphones) and I didn't know how to do that so I googled a bit and tried few suggestion, mainly [Sound from both headphones and speakers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150887/sound-from-both-headphones-and-speakers). I haven't really noticed that it is not a solution for me and after I followed the steps I ented up without sound in linux at all. In Pulse audio manager I had only "Dummy output" and no sound card at all.

After that I have tried a few suggestions how to fix that, mainly removing the alsa driver, pulse audio, purging it, restarting etc. Nothing did help so I tried a few steps from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting. I am pretty sure I have used also some other suggestions unfortunately I don' remember which since nothing helped at all. I still had only the Dummy output.

After that I gave up and just decided to start from fresh, to remove my Ubuntu to Xubuntu to XFCE installation and install clean Xubuntu.

Sometimes during this time I noticed that my internet connection doesn't work at all. I tried in Windows as well and it didn't work. I tried all the usually suggested commands for listing ethernet devices in Linux and nothing showed up there.
I have tried to reset BIOS to default, enable/disable/enable the onboard LAN. Nothing helped at all.

So the question is can you suggest some fix? I had no idea I could remove my ethernet device like this via Linux. The closest to my issue is this topic here [lspci and lshw show no network devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78256/lspci-and-lshw-show-no-network-devices) but I have no idea how to fix that. Would reflashing bios work or what could I try to get my LAN to work again? I am grateful for any suggestion!

sudo lshw -C network   - no output

lspci output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RX780/RX790 Host Bridge
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RX780/RD790 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx0 port A)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD790 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port E)
00:0a.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD790 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port F)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller (rev 40)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:15.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Barts PRO [Radeon HD 6850]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Barts HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6800 Series]
02:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
03:00.0 SATA controller: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB363 SATA/IDE Controller (rev 03)
03:00.1 IDE interface: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB363 SATA/IDE Controller (rev 03)
04:0e.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments TSB43AB23 IEEE-1394a-2000 Controller (PHY/Link)
05:00.0 SATA controller: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB363 SATA/IDE Controller (rev 02)
05:00.1 IDE interface: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB363 SATA/IDE Controller (rev 02)
```

Comment: Have you tried opening your PC and checked whether the card is still in place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearing CMOS by shorting the clear CMOS jumper on my mother board solved the issue so please ignore my questions! After clearing CMOS I loaded default settings in BIOS, customized what I needed and was ready to go again.

However after starting fresh with new Xubuntu installation and doing a few configurations, installations the same issue happened.

I have again tried to enable the simultaneous output however now I tried it by installing paprefs and enabling virtual output device there. (after all I noticed that I just had the devices plugged in wrong holes :D - anyway at least I learned something new.)

Then I hit "Restart" from the menu to restart the PC, after the restart the PC hanged before post screen so basically it didn't boot up. Monitor went into inactive state and nothing happened. I had to force my PC to quit and start it again. After that I was able to boot up however the ethernet card disappeared again.

So I had to clear CMOS again using the jumper on my motherboard and it worked fine again.

When I booted to Xubuntu after this latest clear I noticed that the **ALSA plug-in [plugin-container]** Alsa Playback appeared in **PulseAudio Volume control** which was added there even with the first Ubuntu installation after all the changes I did.

So to conclude I suspect that sometime during the installation of ALSA it does something with BIOS which cause at least on my PC the ethernet card to be removed/disabled. I am not sure what it does or why or whether it is caused by ALSA for sure (70% sure) but clearing CMOS helped in my case to fix the **No etherned card found** issue.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please delete the question.

Comment: The questions you post are not only to help you but also to offer a huge knowledge base for all other Ubuntu users that can look up their issues and learn from the already solved problems. So we don't want you to delete your question, as it can be helpful for future visitors. But I would like to ask you instead to add some detail to your answer (by editing it) - e.g. how you achieved to clear the CMOS and if you can, additional explanations why it helped. Thank you!

Comment: @ByteCommander thank you very much for your input. I have edited my answer and also added some new findings. Hopefully it will help users who have similar issue.

BTW for user68186 who I can't notify in this comment :) - I wanted to remove it once I found out I solved the issue by myself but didn't find a way to do so. After googling for answer I found out that removal of questions isn't desired so I stopped searching. :)